# Can you use/deploy SQL Server Developer edition to Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm working on a solution where we will have a staging area in Azure where we will log ship data from an on premise SQL environment. For cost reasons, I'd like to deploy a Developer edition of SQL server to Azure (where log shipping will occur), but can not find anything from Microsoft which says it can be done.

I need documentation for an answer so if you have an answer, please link me to some type of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can as long as you don't use it for production purposes. Development Editions are meant for Development. Staging environments are part of the development environment the difference being that they are for ensuring your changes will not break production when deployed for real, so you should not have any problem there.

Comment: Have you had any experience in doing this? Or any documentation from Microsoft which says it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Only for test/dev, and now, [as SQL Server DE is free](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/), you can do it in matter of short time + you may receive some cloud credits as a part of Visual Studio Dev Essentials program which includes SQL Server DE.
I did not see any type of docs describing the installation process of exact DE edition. I believe because it is quite straightforward process.